# Adding elements to array problem

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<rowData.length;i++){
    if(rowData[i].title == 'Gender'){
        AddMinusGenderImage.remove(AddMinusGenderImage);
        rowData.splice(i,1);
        tableview.data = rowData;
        break;
    }
}
```

After i remove the data and a new data to the array, it's getting added to array[1] instead of array[0]. why??

**Adding the Array Part**

I add array to element on the click of the button like this. On each click of button, the row is getting added to array.

```
rowData.push(row);
```

row is an object, now it has a property title which i am checking and deleting the row. When i add another row, it's not taking the empty space instead creating a new array index.

Comment: Where do you add data to the array?

Comment: Well, data is always added to the end of the array, never to the beginning. If the removed element was the first one, the up to then second element becomes the frist one and the new one the second. What is that you actually want to do?

Comment: In my case, when i remove the firstone, the second one does not become first also when i add second one too it does not become first

Comment: @JohnCooper: Really? Then your code is either different from you posted or you are using a weird browser. If you remove an element from an array via `splice`, the array is reindexed: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3raxN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ".splice()" function will remove an element from anywhere within your array, but ".push()" *always* adds elements to the **end** of the array.

Thus:

```
var r = ["hello", "out", "there"];
```

If we splice out the middle word ("out"):

```
r.splice(1, 1);
```

Then the array will be `["hello", "there"]`.  However, if we ".push()" something else:

```
r.push("up");
```

Then the array will be `["hello", "there", "up"]`.